# Can't read csv file with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I need to read csv file with d3.js. My data file is

```
x,y
480,200
580,400
680,100
780,300
180,300
280,100
380,400
```

and my code is

```
var ball_1 = []
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    ball_1 = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x"], +d["y"] ]; });
    });
console.log(ball_1)
```

and the console log says

> Array [  ]

but if I just write the data array explicitly in code,

```
var ball_1 = [
    [480, 200],
    [580, 400],
    [680, 100],
    [780, 300],
    [180, 300],
    [280, 100],
    [380, 400]
    ];
console.log(ball_1)
```

Then console log says

> Array [ Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2] ]

So the first code for reading csv file does not work.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3`'s methods `json()`, `csv()` and `tsv()` are asynchronous. that means that you should write

```
var ball = [];

d3.csv('yourfile.csv', function(err, data){
    ball = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x"], +d["y"] ]; });

    console.log(ball); //here the code is executed when the csv is retrieved
});

console.log(ball); //here the code is executed after d3.csv() is launched
```

depending on how fast the server is, you should see

```
Array[]
Array[7]
```